# How should my final regression model be if I have a categorical variable (2 categories) and 3 continuous variable?

Tags: r, computational-statistics

The final model needs to include all variables. I need to analyze the significance of their effects on the dependent variable and then see if there's any difference in effects of continuous variables between the two categories. Is my final model y~x1+x2+x3+x4?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Also, please add some context regarding your situation, your data, and your goals.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It depends on what notation are you using.

Longer answer:

Let's say you have a dummy variable Z1 for your categories, and 3 continuous variables X1, X3, X3.

If you build your model as Y ~ a0 +a1*Z1 + a2*X1 + a3*X2 + a4*X3 you will be able to estimate following thing: holding x1,2,3 fixed, group two will have, on average, values of Y higher by a1 compared to group one.

But you will not be able to judge the different impacts of X1, X2 and X3.

So what should you do?

You should include also multiplicative terms between Z1 and Xs!

Using Y ~ a0 + a1*Z1+a2*X1 + a3*X2 + a4*X3 + a5 * Z1* X1 + a6 * Z1 * X2 + a7 * Z1 *X3, you will be able to say, what happens to individual groups when variables X1,2,3 change. Note that a5, a6 and a7 will contribute to the Y only when the observation falls into category 2 (so that Z1 = 1).

Comment: I get the final model, but how do I use the lm() call for it?

Comment: Something like `fit <- lm(y~as.factor(z)*(x1+x2+x3))` will do the trick. You should also go through the documentation of lm function to learn more about it

Comment: It works well, but I find that when I move the order of the continuous variables, the values from summary(aov()) changes quite alot. Is this a sign of collinearity?

Comment: The first paragraph of the Note in the documentation of aov tells you what I suspect is happening but really this is off-topic here as it is about programming rather than statistics.